# Android: Can anyone help me to parse XML?

Tags: android, json, xml, android-studio

I am creating a gallery app for Android, I started to develop for android recently
I am trying to parse XML, but all examples in the internet doesn't works for me

[XML](http://pastebin.com/raw/BD1aTeqr)

Can anyone parse it for me and send the code please ??

Comment: in this XML, there is JSONObject of fotos first, which returns JsonArray of (foto). On looping this, you will get JSONObjects of title and nome. Hope it helps.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Wait... Opening studio

Comment: [Parser](http://pastebin.com/raw/TdZCrALu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
public List<Foto> getFotos() {
    ArrayList<Foto> array = new ArrayList<>();
    Foto foto = new Foto();

    try {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();

        InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("fotos.xml");
        parser.setInput(inputStream, null);

        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        String text = "";

        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            eventType = parser.next();
            String tagName = parser.getName();

            switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if (tagName.equals("foto")) {
                        foto = new Foto();
                    }
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if (tagName.equals("foto")) {
                        array.add(foto);
                    } else if (tagName.equals("title")) {
                        foto.setTitle(text);
                    } else if (tagName.equals("nome")) {
                        foto.setNome(text);
                    }
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    text = parser.getText();
                    break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return array;
}
```

Foto.java

```
public class Foto {
    String title;
    String nome;

    public Foto() {
    }

    public Foto(String title, String nome) {
        this.title = title;
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, worked!